# Read Airflow UI config file in python code and use the values as parameter

Tags: airflow

I am new to Airflow. I have a DAG.py wherein I am using a BashOperator to run a python script.

I would like to pass some argument for date in this python script using a config file. I see that one can trigger a DAG with a config on the UI:

[image]

I am not sure how I can read this in my DAG.py and pass that to the python script for using as a parameter.

My DAG.py looks like this:

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator


dag = DAG(
      'Sample_DAG', 
      description='DAG for Sample run',
          schedule_interval='@monthly',
          start_date=datetime(2022, 11, 15),
          catchup=False,
          )

bash_op = BashOperator(
    task_id="run_hello_file",
    bash_command= "python3.6 /path/to/hello_world.py",
    dag=dag
)
bash_op
```

Apologies if its a very trivial question but I could not find anything which answers my question.
[Most of the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60556380/airflow-trigger-dag-via-ui-with-parameters-config) just tell how to use the config but not how to read it using python and pass it as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will trigger DAG with config as:

```
{"my_key":"hello"}
```

and your code is:

```
bash_command= "echo {{ dag_run.conf['my_key'] }}"
```

it will print `hello`

[image]

In your case you can use it to pass parameters to your script:

```
bash_command= "python3.6 /path/to/hello_world.py {{ dag_run.conf['my_key'] }}",
```

Example:

[image]

Will be rendered as:
[image]

You can also configure [Params](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts/params.html#params) if you want default parameters for scheduled runs but to allow override them in manual runs.