# Airflow - How can I access an execution parameter in a non templated field?

Tags: python, jinja2, airflow

I've managed to retrieve the execution parameter in my Airflow 1.10.15 dag but only under templated parameters (like PythonOperator and BashOperator) as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663534/for-apache-airflow-how-can-i-pass-the-parameters-when-manually-trigger-dag-via)

I need to use the execution parameter in an operator field that is not templated, namely GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator - field_delimiter and a few others.

Is it possible at all? Any Alternatives?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own operator with the same behavior that adds namespace to `template_fields`:

```
class MyGoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator):
         template_fields = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator.template_fields +('field_delimiter',)
```

Then simply use `MyGoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` as you are used to. It has all the abilities of `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` with additional functionality of `field_delimiter` as templated field.

Note: `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` is deprecated. You should import `GCSToBigQueryOperator` from [google backport provider](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow-backport-providers-google/).